# how to distinguish refreshing of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

using jquery, how can you distinguish between refreshing vs. navigating away from the current URL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not you can't. Unless the navigation is triggered by an event within the current page/window.

See the JQuery events doc for more info: http://docs.jquery.com/Events

There could be some other ways, using cookies or other means for you to do the detection though.

**To Add:**

I found this [alternative](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php), just javascripts and cookies.

Comment: _Just_ javascript & cookies? That's the worst case. But I can't see any alternatives.

Comment: @gs: Without javascript is possible i guess, didn't spend much thought on it. But cookies seems like something convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think there is a Javascript only or Jquery specific way of doing this... but check out [this article](http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_detect_refresh_with_javascript.php) on how it can be done using hidden variables or cookies.  Looks like it won't catch 100% but it might be a start.

Comment: @beggs: hah, we found the same sample. +1 :)